# Can I clone plugin folder to another directory so that I don't have to reinstall them?

Tags: plugins, migration

I built a multisite network and it got broken due to a developer who now claimed that it can't be fixed: The subsites' dashboards can no longer be accessed and the pages give the error message "page cannot be found". Since I haven't worked on it for very long, I am fine with  "abandoning" the site and restarting.

Right now, I would like to move all my installed plugins (paid and non-paid ones) from this site to a new single site installation (not multisite). Is this possible? How do I do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can copy the folders and their contents over. A few caveats:

- they will start as deactivated
- their database records will not be copied over automatically. Some paid plugins store the license key in the database.
- there may be compatibility issues if your new site is on a different version of WordPress, PHP, etc., Especially since you said the site is a couple of years old and you haven't touched it in a while

Personally I would rather try to fix what you have and then go from there. "Can't be fixed" is subjective. If you reinstall the core WordPress files, network deactivate the plugins, and network-wide deactivate non-core themes, you still can't get into the subsites' dashboards?

Comment: "reinstall the core WordPress files, network deactivate the plugins, and network-wide deactivate non-core themes, you still can't get into the subsites' dashboards"

That is correct, my friend. I've tried all these steps but it still couldn't be fixed. I tried using server rewind to undo whatever it is the developer did but it didn't work etiher.

Other developers have quoted me up to USD450 just to fix this problem! Since the site doesn't have too much work done at the moment, I'd rather rebuild it than spend the money.

Comment: And the good thing is, the site is on the latest version of Wordpress. So I guess there shouldn't be any problems with compatability :)

Comment: This is the link of what happened to my site: [link] (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/332381/my-subsites-accidentally-went-from-one-multisite-network-to-another-how-do-i-ch) The developer from the host support has now stated that it cannot be fixed by them and it's outside of their scope of support. Which is why I thought it'd be easier and quicker to just redo the whole thing